# How to add badge on div in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to add badge on div in angular 6?

I have dynamic div in html. I want to increase counter for specific div. For example i have five div whose id is (`div1`, `div2`, `div3`, `div4`, `div5`) and i have one button name increase counter which increase counter for all div but i want to increase counter value for specific div. Please find enclosed file.

Please find snapshot:

[image: Please find snapshot]

i have attached my sample code:

**Here is the html for displaying div:**

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5]; let index" style="height:120px; border:1px solid #ccc">
      Div {{ index }} <label calss="badge badge-default">0</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <p><a (click)="increaseCounter(index)" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer">Increase Counter</a></p>
</div>
```

**Here is the function in .ts file:**

```
increaseCounter(k) {
  this.counter++;
}
```

I want to add counter on specific div.

Please help me how can i do this in angular 6?

Comment: You would need a separate button and counter variable for each div, else how will you know which div you are increasing the count on?

Comment: Yes i got my answer.

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes

Comment: @SiddAjmera suppose i have 20 dynamic div then how can i manage counter. I can't add static.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to tweak this a bit, but you can use [**`Bootstrap's Badges`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/)

Use it' like this:

```
<button (click)="div1Counter = div1Counter + 1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
  DIV 1 <span class="badge badge-light">{{ div1Counter }}</span>
</button>
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igdnhq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<button (click)="counter1 = counter1++" class="btn btn-default">
DIV <label class="badge badge-default">{{ counter1 }}</label>
</button>
```